# Why this command in ggplot is returning an error?

Tags: r, ggplot2, layer

I'm learning ggplot2 and I don't understand why this doesn't work :

```
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat))
p <- p + layer(
     geom = "point",
     stat = "identity"
)
p
Error in as.environment(where) : 'where' is missing
```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is that you haven't specified what to use for the y-values.  ggplot2 doesn't have the same default as the base graphics for plotting points against their index values.  To use `geom_point()` with `stat="identity"` you'd need something like:

```
p<-ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat, y=cut))
p+layer(geom="point", stat="identity")
```

or more commonly

```
p+geom_point(stat="identity")
```

or however else you want try to plot your data.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you don't use `layer` to build up a plot.  Instead, you use `geom` or `stat`.  `p + geom_point()` will plot what you're looking for.  I'd suggest working through some of the examples in the `gplot2` documentation.

Comment: right but by using layer I just wanted to understand what exactly are geom and stat and how they interact

Comment: Moving your data and aesthetics into the `layer` call gives you a proto object back, but I don't know what to do with it:  `layer(data=diamons, aes(x=caret), geom='point', stat='identity')`. However, `stat='identity'` is rather redundant here.